# Facebook Graph API get links and photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We manage to get a page uploaded photos, or links in separate requests, but we would like to get it all in 1 line, including user photos and links together (public page).

Is there a way to get both in 1 request?

`https://graph.facebook.com/id/photos/uploaded` Photos

`https://graph.facebook.com/id/links` Links

If you get the feed of a page, all pictures are very small , and I need a big image :

`https://graph.facebook.com/id/feed/`

Answer (score 1):

Use the attachments field under the feed connection

`https://graph.facebook.com/id/feed?fields=link,attachments`